# add column with names in lapply function (R software)

Tags: r, lapply, quantile

I am using the lapply function to estimate the quantiles of several columns of a list of data frames:

```
stack(lapply(df[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75), **names = c("q0.25, q0.50, q0.75")**))
```

It is working as I expected less the last part of names, how can I create a column in the output table that says what it is each row: q0.25, q0.50, q.075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` which will return matrix with appropriate names :

```
t(sapply(df[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75)))
```

If you want specific names, you can convert data to dataframe and use `setNames`.

```
setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(df[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75)))), 
         c("q0.25", "q0.50", "q0.75"))
```

---

For example, using `mtcars` dataset -

```
setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(mtcars[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75)))), 
          c("q0.25", "q0.50", "q0.75"))

#         q0.25   q0.50  q0.75
#disp 120.82500 196.300 326.00
#hp    96.50000 123.000 180.00
#drat   3.08000   3.695   3.92
#wt     2.58125   3.325   3.61
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `purrr` in one row [i used mtcars for the sake of the example `df <- mtcars`]

```
purrr::map_dfr(df[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75), .id = "names")
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  names  `25%`  `50%`  `75%`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 disp  121.   196.   326   
2 hp     96.5  123    180   
3 drat    3.08   3.70   3.92
4 wt      2.58   3.32   3.61
```

Or in a long-format output:

```
library(purrr)
map(mtcars[3:6], quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75)) %>% 
  map_dfr(tibble::as_tibble, rownames = "quantiles", .id = "names")
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   names quantiles  value
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 disp  25%       121.  
 2 disp  50%       196.  
 3 disp  75%       326   
 4 hp    25%        96.5 
 5 hp    50%       123   
 6 hp    75%       180   
 7 drat  25%         3.08
 8 drat  50%         3.70
 9 drat  75%         3.92
10 wt    25%         2.58
11 wt    50%         3.32
12 wt    75%         3.61
```

---

Since your input is a data.frame and so is your output, you could also use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.0.0
df[3:6] %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), quantile, prob = c(0.25,0.50,0.75)),
              quantiles = paste0("q", c("0.25","0.50","0.75")))
```

```
     disp    hp  drat      wt quantiles
1 120.825  96.5 3.080 2.58125     q0.25
2 196.300 123.0 3.695 3.32500     q0.50
3 326.000 180.0 3.920 3.61000     q0.75
```

Rearrange in a long format, if you wish, by adding this at the end:

```
 %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-quantiles)
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   quantiles name   value
   <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
 1 q0.25     disp  121.  
 2 q0.25     hp     96.5 
 3 q0.25     drat    3.08
 4 q0.25     wt      2.58
 5 q0.50     disp  196.  
 6 q0.50     hp    123   
 7 q0.50     drat    3.70
 8 q0.50     wt      3.32
 9 q0.75     disp  326   
10 q0.75     hp    180   
11 q0.75     drat    3.92
12 q0.75     wt      3.61
```

To sort out, you can always use `dplyr::arrange`